# Spring Cloud Stream default custom message headers

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

Is there a way to configure the default `Message<T>` headers when the message is generated from the method return value:

```
@Publisher(channel = "theChannelname")
public MyObject someMethod(Object param) {
    ...
    return myObject;
}
```

or

```
@SendTo("theChannelname")
public MyObject someMethod(Object param) {
    ...
    return myObject;
}
```

In the examples above the `Message<MyObject>` will be automatically generated.

So, how can I control the default message generation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that via `@Header` annotation for the method arguments:

```
@Publisher(channel="testChannel")
public String defaultPayload(String fname, @Header("last") String lname) {
  return fname + " " + lname;
}
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/message-publishing.html#publisher-annotation

Comment: I marked the answer as accepted because it contains working solution. However, I'd prefer to not impact my interface by infrastructure operations... 
or am I missing something?

Comment: There is no "infrastructure operations". That is exactly how `@Publisher` works: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/message-publishing.html#publisher-annotation. You may really consider to just return the whole `Message` from your method to achieve headers transfer requirements.

Comment: I have an interface method: ```Result createRecord(Object data)```  and in implementation, I'd like to send a result to the Kafka topic. Let's say I can't alter an interface... and I don't want to write the code to do it :) ie ```channel.send(Message<T> message)```

Comment: Is it possible to impact ```Message``` creation process by injecting my own ```MessageConverter```?

Comment: In case of `@Publsiher` you can consider to use `MessagePublishingInterceptor` with the supplied `PublisherMetadataSource`. And in case of `@SendTo` yes, I think `MessageConverter.toMessage()` should do the trick for you

Answer (score 2):

Not really - the assumption is that if you return a payload then you don't care much about the headers. You can have the method return a `Message` and add your own headers there.